# Delete only incoming call in Call Logs in android

Tags: android, calllog

Is it possible to delete only incoming calls from the call log list?

If so how?

I am able to delete all of them easily but not sure how to delete only incoming calls?

Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In [`CallLog`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/provider/CallLog.java) provider database, `android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE` ("type") column will have value 
`android.provider.CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE` (1) for an incoming call record.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method with condition **type = 1**

```
public void delete(final String id, final String number) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor c = cr.query(uri, null, "and type = 1 and _id" + "=?", new String[] { "" + id }, null);
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String pid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String pnumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NUMBER"));
            if (id.equals(pid) && number.equals(pnumber)) {
                context.getContentResolver().delete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, CallLog.Calls._ID + " = ?", new String[] { id });
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

}
```